# F#: Can I use try/with in a constructor that calls to the base class?

Tags: f#, constructor, try-catch

I'm a newbie F# programmer, and I'm having some trouble getting the syntax for my F# program correct.

Essentially, I want to turn this C# code into F#:

```
class MyRiskyObject : BaseObject
{
    private string field;

    public MyRiskyObject(object foo, string data)
        : base(foo)
    {
        try
        {
            this.data = RiskyOperation(data);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```

I, so far, have something like

```
type MyRiskyObject
    inherit BaseObject

    val field : string

    new (foo:object, data:string) = {
        inherit BaseObject(foo)
        try
          field = RiskyOperation()
        ????????
    }
```

I just can't get the syntax right...

---

### Edit:

here is the actual code I'm working on:

```
type RegExpObject = 
  inherit CommonObject

  val RegExp : Regex
  val Global : bool

  member x.IgnoreCase:bool =
    (x.RegExp.Options &&& RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

  member x.MultiLine:bool =
    (x.RegExp.Options &&& RegexOptions.Multiline) = RegexOptions.Multiline

  new (env, pattern, options, global') =
    {
      inherit CommonObject(env, env.Maps.RegExp, env.Prototypes.RegExp) 

      // Here, I need to catch the exception, and instead call RaiseSyntaxError.
      RegExp = new Regex(pattern, options ||| RegexOptions.ECMAScript ||| RegexOptions.Compiled)

      Global = global'
    }
    then RegExp = new Regex(pattern, options ||| RegexOptions.ECMAScript ||| RegexOptions.Compiled)

  new (env, pattern) = 
    RegExpObject(env, pattern, RegexOptions.None, false)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466981/f-non-trivial-non-primary-constructor/4467039#4467039 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746070/adding-code-in-constructor-with-alternative-class-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just delegate the real work to a separate free function, so the work doesn't have to be done directly in your class' constructor?

```
let createRegex pattern options =
  try
    Regex(pattern, options ||| RegexOptions.ECMAScript ||| RegexOptions.Compiled)
  with
  | :? System.ArgumentException -> RaiseSynaxError ()
```

Then your class (as demonstrated in your edit) would be:

```
type RegExpObject(env, pattern, options, global') //'
  inherit CommonObject(env, env.Maps.RegExp, env.Prototypes.RegExp)

  let RegExp = createRegex pattern options
  let Global = global' //'

  member x.IgnoreCase =
    (x.RegExp.Options &&& RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

  member x.MultiLine =
    (x.RegExp.Options &&& RegexOptions.Multiline) = RegexOptions.Multiline

  new (env, pattern) = RegExpObject(env, pattern, RegexOptions.None, false)
```

An advantage here is that, as @Brian indicated, no use of `val` would be necessary, making the class definition much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
type MyRiskyObject(foo : obj, data : string) as this =
    inherit BaseObject(foo)

    let mutable data = data;

    do
        try
            data <- this.RiskyOperation data 
        with 
            | :? System.ArgumentException -> this.DoSomethingElse()
```

Alternate example with non-mutable `let` binding where `RiskOperation` and `DoSomethingElse` are not members of `MyRiskObject`

```
type MyRiskyObject(foo : obj, data : string) =
    inherit BaseObject(foo)

    let data = 
        try 
           OtherModule.RiskyOperation data
        with
        | :? System.ArgumentException -> 
           OtherModule.DoSomethingElse()
           data
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using `let mutable`?  I think I'm bound to using `val`.

Comment: @John it depends. If `RiskyOperation` and `DoSomethingElse` are member functions then I believe you are stuck with mutable.  `let` bindings must be complete before you execute a `do` block and `do` is the first place you can access member functions (IIRC). If they're not member functions then you can embed the `try / with` into the initialization of `data` and remove the mutable.

Comment: `RiskyOperation` is construction of a regex.  I'll post the actual code I'm working with.

Comment: @John posted another version which has a non-mutable `let` binding assuming they aren't member functions.

Comment: Why are you bound to using `val`?  It is very rare to need it, and the syntax around it is ugly.